# How to sort DynamoDB rows by an attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have the following table:

```
ItemUUID (string) | Purchases (number) | Type (string)
--------------------------------------
book-a | 5 | book
book-b | 1 | book
book-c | 10 | book
```

Every time someone buys an item, I would like to increment the `Purchases`.  I then would like to query the table to get the most purchased items (`ItemUUID`s sorted DESC by `Purchases`)

I thought I could make `ItemUUID` a primary key, and make a global secondary index on `Type` with a sort key of `Purchases`.  Then query the GSI where `Type = book`, leave sort key blank, and Sort Descending.

This is not working.  Is my use case possible with DynamoDB?

Answer (score 0):

What I came up with works, but I feel is kinda hack'ish.

**Table definition**

```
Primary partition key   type (String)
Primary sort key        uuid (String)
```

**Global Secondary Index**

```
Primary partition key   type (String)
Primary sort key        purchases (Number)
```

Because GSI's don't have to have unique  partition+sort keys, I can get a way with doing a query where `type=book`, leave purchases blank, sort DESC